# Is there a way I can simplify this boilerplate event handler code in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way I can cut down on this boilerplate code without being too clever?

I have a bunch of event callbacks that do this:

```
HandleFooFinished() {
  FooFinished = true;
}

HandleBarFinished() {
  BarFinished = true;
}
```

I *could* wire these up using lambdas to cut down on the callback code, except for the fact that I need a reference to the handler to unsubscribe, like this.

```
SubscribeToEvents() {
  GameState.Subscribe("OnFooFinished", HandleFooFinished);
  GameState.Subscribe("OnBarFinished", HandleBarFinished);
}

UnsubscribeToEvents() {
  GameState.Unsubscribe("OnFooFinished", HandleFooFinished);
  GameState.Unsubscribe("OnBarFinished", HandleBarFinished);
}
```

Why do I even need to set these flags, anyway, you ask? I'm designing some logic to handle scene transitions, so I'm consolidating the flow logic like this:

```
TransitionFromSceneAToSceneB {
  GameState.FireEvent("DoFooInAnotherScene")
  yield return new WaitUntil(FooFinished);

  // Do bar and baz after foo is done, wait until they both finish 
  GameState.FireEvent("DoBarInAnotherScene");
  GameState.FireEvent("DoBazInAnotherScene");
  yield return new WaitUntil(BarFinished);
  yield return new WaitUntil(BazFinished);

  // Celebrate 
  ...
}
```

What do you think? Have a lookup dictionary for the flags and a helper method that handles the subscribing and unsubscribing? Do something completely different because this is a silly naive approach?

Comment: This may be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you! I looked there and it seems like they want actual working code versus this pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

A helper class with static methods for subsribing and managing callbacks is my preferred way of doing this, usually in pair with OnEnable and OnDisable

While there are many ways to do it, and handling a logic from within the class is certainly valid, but sooner or later you start to push out the functionality to a parent class from which you inherit, which effectically is similar to pushing the handling to a seperate object, but limits your inheritance tree.

Also consider basing the subscrbtion model on implementing an interfacer rather than concrete class structure